# Path integral of $1/(z^2-1)$ along $|z|=2$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

I would like to calculate the path integral $S$ of $1/(z^2-1)$ along the curve $|z|=2$.

Using the parametrization $y: [0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, y(t)=4e^{it}$ and the partial fraction expansion $1/(z^2-1) = -(1/2)/(z+1) + (1/2) / (z-1)$ we get

$S=\int_y 1/(z^2-1) dz = \int_y-(1/2)/(z+1) dz+ \int_y(1/2) / (z-1)dz$.

So to calculate the first integral we would need to determine

$\int_{[0, 2\pi]}e^{it}/(4e^{it}+1)dt$, and a similar expression for the second integral.

How can we continue from here?

Comment: $f(t) = \log(4 e^{it} + 1)$, $f'(t) = ? $ (and this is the real analysis method)

Comment: I have in mind that $1/z$ has no complex antiderivative.

Comment: no complex derivative/antiderivative here, $t \in (0,2\pi)$

Comment: But $e^{it}$ is complex (?)

Comment: $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{it}}{4e^{it}+1} dt$ is a real integral, forget the complex-analysis

Comment: I don't get it. It's a complex valued function, so it's a complex integral.

Comment: no, complex analysis is (mainly) about the derivative and antiderivative of $f(z)$ with respect to the complex variable $z$, here I'm talking of the derivative and antiderivative of $f(t)$ where $t \in (0,2\pi)$, it is real-analysis

Comment: Okay. So assuming we're somehow real, where is the absolute value in your antiderivative?

Comment: ok, you really need to read a complex analysis  course. so if your branch of $\log(z)$ is continuous at $z_0$ then it is differentiable at $z_0$ and $\log'(z_0) = 1/z_0$, so $\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{4 i e^{it}}{4 e^{it} + 1} dt = F(t) \mid_0^{2\pi}$ where $F(t) = \log(4e^{it}+1) + 2 i \pi k(t)$, $k(t) \in \mathbb{Z}$  and $F(t)$ is continuous on $[0,2\pi]$

Comment: Okay, now you've convinced me. The other steps in my attempt are okay (especially the separation into two individual path integrals)? [and you're right, I have no real theoretical background in complex analysis until now, on my way to change this]

Comment: see if you can solve it now (hint : $F(t)\mid_0^{2\pi} \ne 0$)

Comment: (1)  Shouldn't it rather be $log(4e^{it}+1)/(4i)$ (considering the inner derivative as well)?

(2) What is $k(t)$?

Comment: $k(t)$ is the term making $F(t)$ continuous, whatever the branch of $\log$ you are considering..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As regards your integral
$$\begin{align*}\int_{[0, 2\pi]}\frac{e^{it}}{4e^{it}+1}dt&=\int_{[0, 2\pi]}\frac{e^{it}(4e^{-it}+1)}{|4e^{it}+1|^2}dt\\
&=\int_{[0, 2\pi]}\frac{4+\cos t+i\sin t}{17+8\cos t}dt\\
&=2\int_{[0,\pi]}\frac{4+\cos t}{17+8\cos t}dt\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left[t+2 \arctan(3/5 \tan(t/2))\right]_0^{\pi}=\frac{\pi}{2}.\end{align*}$$

However, by using Residue Theorem, it is easy to see that the required complex path integral is zero.

Answer (score 3):

An idea:

$$\frac{\exp(it)}{4\exp(it)+1}=\frac{\exp(it)}{4\exp(it)}\frac{1}{1+\frac{\exp(-it)}{4}}=\frac{1}{4}(\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\frac{\exp(-int)}{4^n})$$
And now integrate term by term.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2-1}$ is a function that is $O\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$ as $|z|\to +\infty$, hence the integral of $f(z)$ over $|z|=R$, for large values of $R$, is bounded in absolute value by $\frac{4\pi R}{R^2-1}$, that goes to zero as $R\to +\infty$. On the other hand, by the residue theorem
$$ \oint_{|z|=2}f(z)\,dz = \oint_{|z|=R}f(z)\,dz \tag{1}$$
for any $R>1$, since the enclosed singularities are just the same, $z=\pm 1$. It follows that:
$$ \oint_{|z|=2}f(z)\,dz = \color{red}{0} \tag{2} $$
and the same holds for any meromorphic function with simple poles that is $O\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$ as $|z|\to +\infty$, as soon as the integration contour is a simple plath enclosing every pole.

Answer (score 1):

There's a more elementary approach to this if you really want to do a computation: first do a partial decomposition $\frac{1}{z^2-1}=-\frac{1}{2(z-1)}+\frac{1}{2(z+1)}$. Then notice the contour integral of two terms are exactly $-2\pi i$ and $2\pi i$ by the definition of winding number. Thus, we get the desired result of $0$.